# jmeter - how to build a request out of a response's results?

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm looking into Jmeter to load test a webapp.

What is done in the real app when a user clicks a button is :
1. an http request is sent to a server and the response contains a list of ids.
2. another request which is formulated by the list of ids is sent to server.
I'm interested in the overall performance of both steps.

for example:

1. send request to http://server.com/getsomething

I get a json looks like:

{"ids":[11,22,33,44,55,66]}

1. I take the ids and build another request like http://server.com/getSomethingElse?

ids=11,22,33,44,55,66

How can I simulate a test like this in jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something of following sort.

- Thread group

  - HTTP Sampler 1 (Send request to http://server.com/getsomething)

    - (one ore more) Regular Expression extractor post processor (Extract IDs).
  - HTTP Sampler 2 (2nd request http://server.com/getsomethingElse?IDs)
  - Tree view listener (To see whats going on)

You may find following beginners jmeter screen cast helpful.

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-e1bad3ad-61cf-4620-9733-e44a74af8a3e/t/jmeter-tutorial-regex-extractor-basics